# Maven/import errors

Tags: java, maven

I have some difficulties with importing libraries to my project.

I used maven and I have the dependencies mentioned below but I still have these errors on the imports

[image]

So these have errors

```
   import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
   import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisOrientation;
   import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisPosition;
   import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.BarDirection;
   import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFBarChartData;
   import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
   import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
   import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
   import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
```

I used Maven and I have these dependencies in my pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>jfree</groupId>
       <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.13</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
         <version>3.17</version>
   </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Do I need other dependencies? Are there other dependencies fore Apache, that I have to add in order to be able to import everything I need....

An accepted answer of an old question similar to mine, propose to reinstall eclipse, but it does not work with me

Comment: Inside eclipse , right click on your Project -> Maven -> Update Project -> Ok , tell me if it works or if you done that already. Also noted that some dependencies are duplicated. Are you sure about your pom and your project structure overall ? ?

Comment: Done, but it does not help. @AntJavaDev

Comment: It seems that xddf package does not exist in version 3.17

Comment: should I search for  another dependency versions, for all all Apaches, or just for xddf ?@samabcde

Comment: nope those dependencies should be enough for your imports, can you also provide a screenshot with your classpath , to check that the dependencies are being fetched properly inside your workspace ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev I checked there is no org.apache.poi.xddf package in poi,poi-ooxml,poi-scratchpad,poi-ooxml-schemas,poi-excelant jars for version 3.17.Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: ye most probably a problem with maven or a problem with your connection. as suggested , could you download Maven , and try to build your project from the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xddf` package is new for version 4.0.0 [which is released on 2018-09-07](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html#4.0.0), just change the version of the dependency to 4.0.0 or later to use it.

<del>[Check the change log of POI](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html) .This version is not released as of 29/08/2018. If you need those package, you may check [this](https://poi.apache.org/devel/guidelines.html) on how to get the version 4.0.0 source code.</del>
[image: 2]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8RZ4.png)

Answer (score 0):

on your pom.xml add this tag < dependencies > i don't see it on the provided code of your pom.xml

without this tag your dependencies will not work .

here is a video link explaining this for you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lO_bJTjCdhM

go to your project , right click on your project node 
select maven from menu , and from sub menu disable maven nature

your project will be converts to java project , go to properties , the location of your project path , 
open command window from the path folder 
and submit this command to clean your project

mvn clean

here is a video how to do that 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fF7etmGwvnw

let me know if the error still remaining i will help you
the problem with maven , there is very details tricks which is hard to explain on text , that's why i keep post video for you , notice the folder collaps when you refresh your project on the video .

Comment: It is my mistake in the question, I did not copy it, but it is already there in the code.@Ahmed Shahin

Comment: go to your project , right click on your project node select maven from menu , and from sub menu disable maven nature

your project will be convertd to java project , go to properties , the location of your project path , open command window from the path folder and submit this command to clean your project

mvn clean

here is a video how to do that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fF7etmGwvnw

let me know if the error still remaining i will help you

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Shahin, In cmd I get, mvn is not recognized as command.

Comment: is its own build lifecycle phase (which can be thought of as an action or task) in Maven. mvn clean install tells Maven to do the clean phase in each module before running the install phase for each module.

Comment: if mvn not working for you 

Way around would be moving M2 from user variables